# Extracting time from PING request

Tags: java, timer, ping, printwriter

I want to send a PING to multiple ip addresses nonstop for 24h and get the output which would be only the time related to each ping request in a text file.

I tried  this method

`str = str.substring(str.indexOf("time="), str.indexOf("ms"));`

but i get an Exception(java code).

I would be glad if you could answer me.

Comment: here is my code and i didn't came to solve the prob :

Answer (score 0):

before that `str.substring(str.indexOf("time="), str.indexOf("ms"));` 
line check that str contain `time=`and `ms`. I think that will solve your problem